# How to install 64 bit openGL in linux

Tags: linux, 64-bit, nvidia-graphics-card, opengl

I bought a new system with an NVIDIA GeForce 9000 graphics card. I downloaded the 64-bit NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-190.53-pkg2 from the NVIDIA web site which I have installed in my linux kernel 2.6.26. While it was installing it created 32-bit OpenGL but I want to create 64-bit OpenGL. How do I create it?

Comment: What distribution do you use? And if you say Ubuntu, why didn't you just use the driver provided by the system?

Comment: why would you need 64 bit opengl when most of the graphics cards today dont even support 64 bit int or float

Answer (score 1):

No need. The NVidia driver installed the default architecture OpenGL driver (64bit) and you choose the optional step of also installing 32bit OpenGL. You've got both installed now.

If you're having a specific problem (application won't run, opengl doesn't work, crashes), the n post the errors/logs you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look for a pre-packaged version for your distribution, as this is certainly the easiest way to go about doing things. If for some reason you can't get a prepackaged driver, the following information may assist you.

Now, as for installing 64-bit support, the latest Linux driver package **should** have already installed it. What may be causing this issue is simply that your distributions library search paths don't include where the installer put the library.

It's been a little while since I needed to know where nVidia's installer likes to put things, so I can't give you an authoritative answer on where to find it, though I'd expect it to be called libGL.so somewhere under /usr/lib64.

A few commands that may help you here:

- `locate libGL.so` - Searches the filesystem using a pre-built database for the library. This should find both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions.
- `updatedb` - If you've only recently installed the drivers, run this first. It will rebuild the database used by `locate`. Alternatively, you could use `find \ -name libGL.so*`.
- `file libGL.so.x.y.z` - Will tell you if it's a 32-bit or 64-bit library. Note that this won't work on symlinks.

If you find yourself needing to amend the library search path to include this, expect the configuration steps to be distro-specific. The main environment variable you'll be looking for will be `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. However, different distros have different approaches to managing environment variables. I'd certainly recommend taking the time to understand what you're changing if you need to amend this.