# there is some error which force me to install opengl v2 or higher

Tags: drivers, opengl

I need to a driver which provides **opengl 2.0** or higher to solve an fatal Error...
Because one of my apps needs its drivers

Comment: You install OpenGL by installing your GPU's [drivers](http://superuser.com/questions/88843/how-to-install-64-bit-opengl-in-linux) or [this](http://superuser.com/questions/298443/how-can-i-tell-if-opengl-is-installed-on-a-windows-machine) or [this](http://superuser.com/questions/298443/how-can-i-tell-if-opengl-is-installed-on-a-windows-machine) or even [this](http://superuser.com/questions/464708/regarding-opengl-driver)

Answer (score 1):

You haven't given us any information to work with - OS, graphics card, manufacturer, etc...

I'd suggest getting IOBit's [Driver Booster](http://www.iobit.com/driver-booster.php) (free version available) & see what it advises.

BTW, I don't know of any graphics card or driver set from the past 10 years that can't handle OGL2.1